# Copying fields while maintaining whitespace

Tags: bash, awk, whitespace

I have two files, one  (calc_coord.txt) which I need to copy the x,y,z (fields 3,4,5) coordinates into original_coord.txt. My problem is I can't maintain the correct spacing. I need all the digits to start at the same position (ie, negative sign should be infront of every number down the field).

(calc_coord.txt):

```
 C           6.0  -9.6300406713  -7.9721184039   0.1185895513
 C           6.0  -0.7745844593   0.1157508364  -6.4312181651
 O           8.0  -0.7886186832   8.3312194003   5.1214418928
 H           1.0  -8.5173944199  -1.0344814844   4.2057188615
 H           1.0  -1.3188019701  -1.9268396739  -3.3069629312
 H           1.0  -2.6875350807  -9.7931820111  -2.1222787934
 H           1.0  -0.9445605850   1.2508093202   1.0754040709
 O           8.0   7.0683517839  -0.7860544158   0.0997975722
 H           1.0  -0.5981284452   3.1733024008  -9.5005808667
 C           6.0   2.0350058476   0.2023241539  -9.0066961578
 H           1.0   2.9345243074  -4.1229157611   9.5464726503
 H           1.0   6.3575306659   0.4164272327  -9.0466036794
 H           1.0   1.7357929841   5.1723014064   9.4397462018
```

file I want to copy coordinates into (original_coord.txt):

`@<TRIPOS>ATOM
    1 C   -1.6300406713  -0.9721184039   0.1185895513    C.3       1  LIG1 0.0000 ***** 
    2 C   -0.7745844593   0.1157508364  -0.4312181651    C.3       1  LIG1 0.0000 ***** 
    3 O   -0.7886186832   1.3312194003   0.1214418928    O.3       1  LIG1 0.0000 ***** 
    4 H   -1.5173944199  -1.0344814844   1.2057188615    H         1  LIG1 0.0000 ***** 
    5 H   -1.3188019701  -1.9268396739  -0.3069629312    H         1  LIG1 0.0000 ***** 
    6 H   -2.6875350807  -0.7931820111  -0.1222787934    H         1  LIG1 0.0000 ***** 
    7 H   -0.9445605850   1.2508093202   1.0754040709    H         1  LIG1 0.0000 ***** 
    8 O    1.0683517839  -0.7860544158   0.0997975722    O.3       1  LIG1 0.0000 ***** 
    9 H   -0.5981284452   0.1733024008  -1.5005808667    H         1  LIG1 0.0000 ***** 
   10 C    2.0350058476   0.2023241539  -0.0066961578    C.3       1  LIG1 0.0000 ***** 
   11 H    2.9345243074  -0.1229157611   0.5464726503    H         1  LIG1 0.0000 ***** 
   12 H    2.3575306659   0.4164272327  -1.0466036794    H         1  LIG1 0.0000 ***** 
   13 H    1.7357929841   1.1723014064   0.4397462018    H         1  LIG1 0.0000 *****`

When I try to use awk, I get the format of the coordinates as:

```
@<TRIPOS>ATOM
    1 C   -9.6300406713  -7.9721184039  0.1185895513       C.3       1  LIG1 0.0000 *****
    2 C   -0.7745844593  0.1157508364   -6.4312181651      C.3       1  LIG1 0.0000 *****
    3 O   -0.7886186832  8.3312194003   5.1214418928       O.3       1  LIG1 0.0000 *****
    4 H   -8.5173944199  -1.0344814844  4.2057188615       H         1  LIG1 0.0000 *****
    5 H   -1.3188019701  -1.9268396739  -3.3069629312      H         1  LIG1 0.0000 *****
    6 H   -2.6875350807  -9.7931820111  -2.1222787934      H         1  LIG1 0.0000 *****
    7 H   -0.9445605850  1.2508093202   1.0754040709       H         1  LIG1 0.0000 *****
    8 O   7.0683517839   -0.7860544158  0.0997975722       O.3       1  LIG1 0.0000 *****
    9 H   -0.5981284452  3.1733024008   -9.5005808667      H         1  LIG1 0.0000 *****
   10 C   2.0350058476   0.2023241539   -9.0066961578      C.3       1  LIG1 0.0000 *****
   11 H   2.9345243074   -4.1229157611  9.5464726503       H         1  LIG1 0.0000 *****
   12 H   6.3575306659   0.4164272327   -9.0466036794      H         1  LIG1 0.0000 *****
   13 H   1.7357929841   5.1723014064   9.4397462018       H         1  LIG1 0.0000 *****
```

As you can see the formatting gets a bit messed up when I try to overwrite the fields. It prints the fields all starting at the same position regardless of if there is a "-" or not. Any advice? I have been using this to copy the three fields. Thanks!

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {v[FNR]=$3; next}
    {print substr($0,1,10) sprintf("%-14s", v[FNR]) substr($0,25)}
' calc_coord.txt original_coord.txt >updated_coord.txt
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate, it's hard to see what you're asking. What exactly are you copying? Which spacing is undesired? Because it seems the spacing is messed up from the second file, which is an input file of your problem.. Which of these files is `calc_coord.txt´, which is `original_coord.txt` and which is ´updated_coord.txt`?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to update my question to make it more clear.

Comment: I just need to replace fields 3,4,5 in original_coord.txt with fields 3,4,5 in calc_coord.txt. problem is the formatting. I want to maintain exact formatting in original_coord.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't even get your files to copy/paste without line wrapping, etc so untested try:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { saved[NR]=substr($0,10,20); next }
{ print substr($0,1,5) saved[FNR] substr($0,26) }
' calc_coord.txt original_coord.txt
```

Change the substr() arg numbers to whatever you're looking for.

Comment: This does exactly what I want...I'm pretty new to bash, thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Get the books Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson and Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Great, I will look into both of these today :)